# Draw nodes with tikz above each other

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

How can I draw nodes horizontally listed next to each other but with two nodes vertically listed as in the figure.

[image]

## MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=4.5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2.5em, font=\footnotesize, fill opacity=0.3, text opacity=1]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.5cm]
    \node [block] (a1) {A1};

    \node [block, right=of a1] (a2) {A2};
    \node [block, right=of a2] (a3) {A3};
    \node [block, right=of a3] (a4) {A4};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `above right` or `below right` as a possible parameter for `node`.

For instance:

```
\node [block, above right=of a1] (a2) {A2};
```

You can also use seperate distances for above or right:

```
\node [block, above right=2cm and 1cm of a1] (a2) {A2};
```

To recreate your image example, you'd use:

```
\node [block, right=of a1] (a2) {A2};
\node [block, above right=of a2] (a3) {A3};
\node [block, below right=of a2] (a3b) {A3b};
\node [block, below right=of a3] (a4) {A4};
```

[image: Output of above LaTeX code]